# Probability of detecting a shift in fraction nonconforming control chart

Tags: quality-control

I try to solve a problem (number 7.7) in the 6-th edition of the book 'Statistical Quality Control, a modern introduction' of Douglas Montgomery. Here is the statement:

*A control chart indicates that the current process fraction nonconforming is 0.02. If fifty items are inspected each day, what is the probability of detecting a shift in the fraction nonconforming to 0.04 on the first day after the shift? By the end of the third day following the shift?*

My approach is the following:

I calculated my upper and lower control limits , UCL and LCL respectively, given by

$$
UCL = p + 3\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}},
$$

$$
LCL = p - 3\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}},
$$

where $p$ is the fraction of nonconforming and $n$ is the sample size of each 'trial'.

So, in my case, I have $p=0.02$ and $n = 50$ leading to $UCL = 0.079$ and $LCL = -0.039$. But since a negative value for $LCL$ does not make sense, then it is set to $0$, i.e. $LCL = 0$.

So, for the first question, we are looking to this value

$$
\mathbb{P}(detecting \ a \ shift \ of \ p \ to \ 0.04|p = 0.04),
$$
the latter is equivalent to (from my point of view)

$$
\mathbb{P}(D \geq USL \cdot n| p = 0.04) + \mathbb{P}(D \leq LSL \cdot n| p = 0.04) = 1- \sum_{k=0}^{0.079 \cdot 50} \binom{50}{k} 0.04^k \cdot 0.96^{50-k} + 0.96^{50}= 0.269,
$$

where $D$ is the number of records that are outside the limits. this result is not the correct one, the correct answer is $0.278$. Does anyone have an idea?